# sendgrid php example - how to add sender's name?

Tags: php, sendgrid

In the sendgrid php example here http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html you have the ability to add sender's email but not the sender's name. So say for example if the name of the sender is assigned variable $name, how can I properly add it to the example so that the sender's name is shown as, for example, Bob  rather than just bob@email.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the answer is

```
setFromName($name)
```

Comment: That looks like an earlier version of the PHP API. In the current version, you set the name with the email address, as in the following example:

```php
$mail->setFrom("user@example.org", "George Harrison");
```

Answer (score 4):

Per [the documentation on the php mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), set the *From* header.  With the SendGrid class, I think it might be something like this:

```
$mail->addHeader("From", $name);
```

Comment: Sorry, I just tried it and I still only see the email address :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Would be awesome if you could open an issue on the github repo so we can get this documented!

Comment: Happy to help, but according to OP, this didn't even work.  What type of issue would you like me to open on github?  (Note: I haven't bothered testing mine or OPs answers myself at this point).

Answer (score 0):

Full example with inline images, look (Check out how **cid:myimagecid** is used)

```
$sg = new \SendGrid("<YOUR API KEY>");
$from = new SendGrid\Email("Somebody", "etc@example.com");
$subject = "Bla bla";
$to = new SendGrid\Email("Somebody Else", "dest@example.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", 'Your html <img src="cid:myimagecid">');
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$file = 'path/file.jpg';
$file_encoded = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
$attachment = new SendGrid\Attachment();
$attachment->setContent($file_encoded);
$attachment->setType("image/jpeg");
$attachment->setContentID("myimagecid");
$attachment->setDisposition("inline");
$attachment->setFilename("filename.jpg");

$mail->addAttachment($attachment);

try {
    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
var_dump($response);
```

Works same when using templates.